# append to Jquery multi select drop down is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-multiselect

I am using jquery multiselect dropdown search filter in which iam appending the values to the drop down by getting the search term by the user. when i was trying to append in the below way, i am getting the values in to the data, but can't able to append to it. Below is the code i am using.

```js
$("#SearchOptionsFilter").multiselect({}).multiselectfilter({
                filter: function (event, matches) {
                    var searchKeyword = event.currentTarget.value;
                   $.ajax({
                url: "/_layouts/workdesign/WorkflowHandler.ashx?workType=WorkValuesBySearchKeyword&SearchKeyword=" + searchKeyword + "",
                type: 'POST',
                datatype: 'json',
                contentType: "application/json; charset-utf-8",
                success: function (data) {
                    var obj = data;
                    $.each(obj, function (i, val) {
                        $("#SearchOptionsFilter").append($("<option></option>").attr("value", val.Id).text(val.Name));
                    });
                },
                error: function (xhr) {
                    alert("Something seems Wrong");
                }
            });
                }
            });
```

Also tried by making ajax call as a function outside and called from the multiselectfilter still facing same issue. Is there any way to append the values to the option, please suggest me a way to make it success, thanks in advance for your valuable suggestions.

FYI- We are using jQuery MultiSelect UI Widget 1.13.
 * jQuery MultiSelect UI Widget Filtering Plugin 1.5pre
 * Copyright (c) 2012 Eric Hynds

Comment: Please confirm if the ID of the dropdown is correct. Also what data are you receiving in `data` variable? Check console for errors.

Comment: @SandeshGupta Id is correct and data will be like {id:"123",Name:"abcd"}, we are using the same code format in several places also, but never got this kind of issue. My doubtis because of performing the action inside the multiselectfilter({}).

Comment: Are you getting any errors in console?

Comment: @SandeshGupta, No Sir, not a single error.

Comment: Do one thing.  Add a `console.log(data)` in success function. And confirm what data is coming.

Comment: @SandeshGupta, it is a list of arrays with each object has a value of 
id:108
Name: "advertise"